# How can I get the dead or killed Appstate for an Android app in React Native?

Tags: android, react-native, lifecycle

I implemented android app to push scheduled notification & detect the incoming call state. I have done both things. Now how can I get the dead or killed state to set these things for the state when the app is killed.

The AppState only gives the **active, inactive & background** stages of an the app. How can I get the can the killed or dead state in react native?

This code don't give the killed or dead state.

````
import { AppState, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

const AppStateExample = () => {
  const appState = useRef(AppState.currentState);
  const [appStateVisible, setAppStateVisible] = useState(appState.current);

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = AppState.addEventListener("change", nextAppState => {
      if (
        appState.current.match(/inactive|background/) &&
        nextAppState === "active"
      ) {
        console.log("App has come to the foreground!");
      }

      appState.current = nextAppState;
      setAppStateVisible(appState.current);
      console.log("AppState", appState.current);
    });

    return () => {
      subscription.remove();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Current state is: {appStateVisible}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});

export default AppStateExample;```
````

Comment: Correct me if im wrong, but if its killed/dead the app cant execute code anyway, right? So unless you are trying to determine whether the app is being loaded after coming from the foregorund vs a fresh start there really wouldnt be a use case for knowing if the app is killed, right

Comment: Then how can I set the call detection if the app is closed?

Comment: `if (nextAppState === 'inactive') {
   console.log('the app is closed');
  } `
Try this

Comment: ```if (nextAppState === 'inactive') {    console.log('the app is closed');   } ``` not worked